# Ceph usage control

Tags: ceph, radosgw

Im using Ceph nautilus with 3 node OSD+mgr and 2 node monitor+rgw. What i need is, i want to track any user usage. Im using Ceph as Object Storage and i need to get a report or info about any object gateway user's details such as how many documents written, how much size its using etc. I found some articles about to enable usage on rados gateway (*http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/radosgw.8.html*) and i did.

but when i type  `sudo radosgw-admin usage show --bucket=test --start-date=2020-07-17`

i got
`{ "entries": [], "summary": [] }`

Is there any way get these informations? Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You should enable usage log for rgw in `ceph.conf`:

```
rgw enable usage log = true
```